# jquery library download - stored in browser cache?

Tags: jquery

If I keep reloading a page that uses jquery from google hosted site.
Does that mean it will always redownload the library?
Or does the browser know not to, since it previously downloaded it.

Comment: Define 'reloading'; pressing the reload button on your browser or pressing Ctrl+F5?

Comment: @Tejs: F5 also reloads the page. did you downvote this? if so, very unfair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most modern browsers know not to download that. Check jQuery CDN in console and you see this.

> 304 Not modified.

That means the library is being loaded from cache.

Answer (score 3):

What you are talking about is a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). Typically no, it won't redownload it, and if developers from other sites also use the same CDN, then it may already be in cache even before they get to your website.

Answer (score 0):

The whole reason for using the google hosted version is that if the browser downloaded it from there when visiting any other site it will use a cached copy instead of downloading one from your site.

So simply the answer is yes it will use the one previously downloaded unless told to refresh the cache (ctrl+f5 in chrome for example)

Comment: partially true. there are many other reasons. top three being Decreased Latency, Increased parallelism and Better caching